# How to find out when image is not captured in Landscape mode ie by rotating the phone not camera orientation.

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the default camera of phone which is in Landscape mode. If i captured the image in Landscape mode it fits well in the imageview. But when i rotate the device the image rotates through 90 degree. The camera mode is still Landscape at that time. I am trying to find out when image is not captured in Landscape mode ie by rotating the phone not camera orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933085/android-camera-intent-saving-image-landscape-when-taken-portrait/12933632#12933632) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933085/android-camera-intent-saving-image-landscape-when-taken-portrait). Basically, you'll have to read the orientation information that is stored into the picture (EXIF meta data). There it is stored how the device was oriented, when the image was taken. In my answer, some code is given to rotate the image to be correctly shown in portrait mode.