# How to save Image in portrait in Android?

Tags: android, image, camera

In my android application I am using custom camera for capturing image when I am capturing the image is storing correctly but when i upload that image to server it is saving in both landscape and portrait.

My question is it is possible to upload the image to server only in landscape mode even if the picture is taken in portrait mode. please help me any one in this.

Comment: "it is saving in both landscape and portrait." image cannot be both portrait and landscape...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Camera Intent Saving Image Landscape When Taken Portrait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933085/android-camera-intent-saving-image-landscape-when-taken-portrait)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is posible try it.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90F);
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),   matrix, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
```