# Android camera background rotating

Tags: java, android, camera, photo

I take a photo using the native camera and then when i display it in my android app if it the photo is portrait then it automatically displays the photo in landscape. I do want the photo in landscape but is there a way to force the image to stay in whatever orientation it is.

For instance if it is taken in portrait then when the photo is displayed i just want it to stay how it is instead of android automatically rotating the image and stretching it.

I have tried forcing the camera into landscape using MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION and setting this to landscape but it still tries to rotate the image when i load it up.

I know you can get the orientation of the file and rotate in real time but I don't see the need to do this I just want the photo to display however it is regardless of orientation.

Thanks

Edit: Imagine you take a photo portrait, now if you rotate the phone (not the image) then you still have a portrait image but it is display in landscape (this is what I want) but android rotates the image to landscape which stretches it etc...

Answer (score 0):

For now, there's a bug in the camera. Google's not fixed this yet.

An alternative way, turn on the system Auto-Rotation, photo taken will stay the orientation it was in the preview.

Comment: I don't think its a bug, as android is trying to rotate my portrait image to landscape (as my imageview is landscape) however I want to stop this from happening. In other words i want auto rotation disabled not enabled if you get me?

Comment: I understand what you mean, and I'm also stuck in the part for a long time. If you Google this issue, you could find a lot of discussions about this bug in Google groups. If you'd like to handle the photo yourself, check this question:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933085/android-camera-intent-saving-image-landscape-when-taken-portrait)