# Captured image always shows landscape and setRotate cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, image, android-camera, landscape-portrait

There are quite a few similar topics and issues around here and I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12933632/5257704) . But I get error.

**My Code**

```
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            //h=0;
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    //pic = photo;
                    break;
                }
            }

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                bitmapOptions.inDither = true;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);
                Global.img = bitmap;

                b.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                //p = path;
                f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {

                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    //pic=file;
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            // h=1;
            //imgui = selectedImage;
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            Log.w("path of image ******", picturePath + "");
            b.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }


    }
    else
    {
        finish();
    }

}
```

After follow the tutorial, I have changed my code to

```
  try {
             Bitmap bitmap;
             BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
             bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
             bitmapOptions.inDither = true;
             bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);
              BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
              Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), opts);
              ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getAbsolutePath());
              String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
              int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) :  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
               int rotationAngle = 0;
               if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) rotationAngle = 90;
               if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) rotationAngle = 180;
               if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) rotationAngle = 270;
               Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
               matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle, (float) bm.getWidth() / 2, (float) bm.getHeight() / 2);
               Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bitmapOptions.outWidth, bitmapOptions.outHeight, matrix, true);
               Global.img = bitmap;
               b.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               String path = android.os.Environment
                          .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                           + File.separator
                           + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    //p = path;

                    f.delete();

                    OutputStream outFile = null;

                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
```

1. setRotate in matrix.setRotate cannot be solved.
2. I get a red line underneath `(bm, 0, 0, bitmapOptions.outWidth, bitmapOptions.outHeight, matrix, true);` (cannot resolved method createBitmap )

*********Edit*********

After I import `android.graphics.Matrix` instead of `android.opengl.Matrix,` the app crashed.

**LogCat error**

```
  Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 13045
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:928)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:901)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:833)
            at com.example.project.project.ImageFitScreen.onActivityResult(ImageFitScreen.java:236)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5643)
```

This is line 236

```
 Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bitmapOptions.outWidth, bitmapOptions.outHeight, matrix, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(),matrix, true);

Comment: I still get the same error. Between, variable `rotatedBitmap` is never used. I follow the tutorial but it didn't show where should assign the `rotatedBitmap`

Comment: if u want to fix your rotation problem you need to use rotatedBitmap that u assigned in code

Comment: What should I write next? How to use?

Comment: Global.img = rotatedBitmap ;
 b.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap )

Comment: still getting the same error `11-06 12:18:12.836    1874-1874/com.example.project.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 1874
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:928)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:901)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:833)
            at com.example.project.project.ImageFitScreen.onActivityResult(ImageFitScreen.java:236)`

Comment: try removing  lines bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
             bitmapOptions.inDither = true; and let me know

Comment: are you dealing with large image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94384/discussion-between-seng-and-nisarg).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you imported the wrong Matrix class, you should import android.graphics.Matrix, not android.opengl.Matrix, please double check.