# How can I open front camera using Intent in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

I want to make a app in which I have to open only front camera, How can i do it using `intent`?

```
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: Will you post complete solution of opening front camera?

Answer (score 16):

**java**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri photoUri = Uri.fromFile(getOutputPhotoFile());
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**Other/Alternate Solution**

```
private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    return cam;
}
```

add these permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

> **only available in Gingerbread(2.3) and Up Android Version.**

otherwise you can also check these example

[**1. android-Camera2Basic**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

[**2. Camera Example 2**](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/camera-hardware/android-camera-example/)

[**3. Vogella example**](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html)

hope it helps you..

Comment: I used camera API to open front camera but after capturing image it save image after rotating 90 degree clock wise. How can i save image correctly.

Comment: may be this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12933632/6617272) will help you

Answer (score 4):

Note: you're trying to use Intent correctly (and also note @skydroid answer below). However, it doesn't work for you probably because of below:

## Standard Android Camera

Using `Intent` you only open the standard android camera application (back camera is default there).

**Never use** `android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING` property - this is an undocumented feature that **stopped working** starting from some of the android versions.

## Camera API

To open a front camera you should **use Camera API** - do things like choosing the front camera, showing a preview in a view, and taking pictures manually. Answer of @skydroid shows how to find the front camera. Note that `Camera.open()` doesn't open a camera for the user as you might expect, you should manually show the preview.

Also note, since **API level 21** the Camera API is deprecated and docs recommend to use [Camera 2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) instead. But Camera API remains fully functional and you have no other choice if you want support older versions (< API level 21) as well.

Comment: And the question remains: "How can I open the front camera using Intent in android?" ????

Comment: @ekashking Both author and "skydroid" below already show correct usage of Intent to do that. I only noted that using an Intent for front camera "is an undocumented feature that stopped working starting from some of the android versions" therefore it's not good idea to use it (and probably that's why it doesn't work for author). As an alternative, I mentioned Camera API is preferred option (in case author wasn't aware) and pointed to "skydroid" answer, because he already described Camera API (as well as Intent) usage nicely. P.S. Note, this answer is 5 years old, things might have changed now.

Answer (score 3):

```
try this:

 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
                File outPutFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + Util.SD_CARD_PATH);
                if (!outPutFile.exists()) {
                    outPutFile.mkdirs();
                }
                capturedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(File.createTempFile("packagename" + System.currentTimeMillis(), ".jpg", outPutFile));

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Util.REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

Comment: What is capturedImageUri ?

Comment: its is same as your fileuri. It will store the clicked image in that uri

Comment: it is my SD card path..you can give urs where you want to store it

Comment: What is Util.? Please help Me.

Comment: replace that with "/urappname"..util is my custom class

Comment: No, its not working. It not open front camera. it just open camera where i can choose front camera or back camera. But i want to openly only front camera on launch or at first time.

Comment: try this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102857/android-open-front-camera-as-default