# How our app can act as gallery and become phot chooser app and provide photos back to the other apps?

Tags: android, gallery

In android, if i want to select photos(example from whatsapp), many options will popup like gallery ,camera etc. If we select gallery , we can choose a photo and same will be provided to the parent app. How do i create an app like this gallery?

Comment: For the camera you can use  :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423351/how-can-i-open-front-camera-using-intent-in-android :: for the gallery  take a look at this solution :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978566/how-to-get-selected-image-from-gallery-in-android

Comment: @Barns thanks for your comment, my app wants to be a content provider not a content requester.

Comment: Good!  Could you provide a little bit more information and detail about the app in your post.  "i want to select photos"  sounds like you would like to access the "image" directory and ",camera etc"  sounded like your wanted to access the camera functions in order to grab an image using the integrated camera service. More detail in your post would be very helpful.

Comment: @Mohammedmansoor You mean your app should display in the intent(share) tray?