# Open front camera using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, camera, front-camera

Hello friends I want to use front camera in my app using

> MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

This is the method which I'm using

```
 public void CaptureImage(int request){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, request);
}
```

But it open back camera , what I want is front camera of device.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39423732/7666442

Comment: tried already Nilesh

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39425003/192373. Unless you use camera API (or a library that wraps camera API), you cannot rely on intent extras.

Answer (score 2):

I have use this code to open front camera

use this line in camera intent to open front camera

**intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);**

**Code**

```
    /*for getting image using camera*/
private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, GlobalString.REQUEST_CAMERA);
}
```