# Saved Bitmap has incorrect orientation

Tags: java, android, bitmap

This question has been asked countless times, but none of them actually fix the rotation issue when saving a `Bitmap`.

This is how I initially saved a `Bitmap` to my device:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mStringFilePath);
//Time is us
int mPresentationTime = mPlayer.getPresentationTime();
Bitmap mBitmap = mmr.getFrameAtTime(mPresentationTime, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);

File mFileBitmap = new File(directoryToStore, "test.png");
try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFileBitmap);
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above saves the `.png` with the wrong orientation.

I then saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12933632/8199772) answer, but the problem is that it rotates the, already saved, `Bitmap` to the correct orientation. This is fine if you want to set the `Bitmap` to a `ImageView`, for example. But, what if I want to share the `Bitmap`, or want to open it in the devices Gallery, the orientation would then still be incorrect. I would then have to  do the same process as above - `FileOutputStream` etc. This will then just cause the same issue.

How can I save a `Bitmap` to the device with the correct orientation?

### Edit 1

Trying the answer provided by [Long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52198676/8199772).

I created a new class called `RotateBit`, with the 2 method you provided. I then changed my code to this:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mStringFilePath);
//Time is us
int mPresentationTime = mPlayer.getPresentationTime();
Bitmap mBitmapBeforeRotation = mmr.getFrameAtTime(mPresentationTime, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);

int rotatingInt = RotateBit.getBitmapOriention(mStringFilePath);
Bitmap mBitmap = RotateBit.rotateBitmap(mBitmapBeforeRotation, rotatingInt);

File mFileBitmap = new File(directoryToStore, "test.png");
try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFileBitmap);
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But still the rotation is incorrect.

### Edit 2

I noticed that this issue is related to `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever`, when using `MediaMetadataRetriever` this issue doesn't happen.

Comment: you have `Bitmap mBitmap` so rotate it and then save

Comment: @pskink Please see Edit 1.

Comment: `"rotation is incorrect."` meaning what? what do you have in `rotatingInt`?

Comment: @pskink If the video was recorded in portrait, I then want to save the bitmap to the same dimensions (portrait), but instead the `Bitmap`/png is rotated 90degrees to the left.

Comment: what do you have in `rotatingInt`? tried to use `Log.d`?

Comment: @pskink it returns `0`.

Comment: @pskink please see Edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getBitmapOriention(String path){
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    int orientation = 0;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(path);
        orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
        //Log.e("getBitmapOriention", "getBitmapOriention: "+orientation );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return orientation;
}
/**
 * @param bitmap bitmap from path
 * @param orientation ExifInterface
 * @return oriention flag
 */
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            return bitmap;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
            matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            break;
        default:
            return bitmap;
    }
    try {
        Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return bmRotated;
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

it worked for me

```
rotateBitmap(mBitmap,getBitmapOriention(mPath));
```

Comment: Please see Edit 1

Comment: This code worked fine with my device. Some Samsung devices also work well, but with your device I still have not found a solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ExifInterface` for rotation.

```
public static void normalizeImageForUri(Context context, Uri uri, ImageView imgImageView) {
        try {
//            Log.d(TAG, "URI value = " + uri.getPath());
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(getRealPathFromURI(context, uri));
//            Log.d(TAG, "Exif value = " + exif);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, orientation);
            imgImageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

**For checking rotation of bitmap:**

```
private static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
        try {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();

            return bmRotated;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**More details you refer this links :**

[How to get the Correct orientation of the image selected from the Default Image gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478765/how-to-get-the-correct-orientation-of-the-image-selected-from-the-default-image)

https://github.com/google/cameraview/issues/22#issuecomment-269321811

Comment: Let me try this because I used a app to get the Exif info from the video file and the rotation is 90. So, this might just work.

Comment: Strangely, when I run the video through FFmpeg then try to save the image, the rotation is correct.

Comment: What device are you used?

Comment: Samsung J7 Pro. Yes I did try this.

Comment: Every Samsung device has orientation issue. And that has perfectly Working in my application.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get this working on all devices.

Comment: Yes and for that you need to set ExifInterface for that

Comment: You are getting rotation 0 means you have rotated that image but you have facing an issue with saving that file.

Comment: Make sure you have given READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your application.

Comment: And try with this way for storing rotated image https://github.com/google/cameraview/issues/22#issuecomment-363047917

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to create a work-around. This is probably not how it should be done, but for now, it works.

---

My `Activity` is set to portrait/landscape depending on the rotation of the video that I'm playing. So, I can use this to determine whether or not to rotate the `Bitmap`.

I first create a `Bitmap` like I previously did:

```
Bitmap mBitmapBeforeRotation = mmr.getFrameAtTime(mPresentationTime, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

Then I get the rotation of the screen, the width/hight of the `Bitmap` and rotate the `Bitmap` accordingly:

```
int mBitW = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mBitmapBeforeRotation.getWidth()));
int mBitH = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mBitmapBeforeRotation.getHeight()));

int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
// Do nothing because Landscape doesn't give wrong Bitmap rotation
} else {
    if (mBitW>mBitH){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap fixedBitmapRotation = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmapBeforeRotation, 0, 0, mBitmapBeforeRotation.getWidth(), mBitmapBeforeRotation.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    String nameOfImage = "nameOfImage" + ".jpeg";
    final File mFile = new File(directoryyToStore, nameOfImage);

    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
        fixedBitmapRotation.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    texeBit = mp.getPath();

}
```

---

Just a side note. **I don't have to use the rotation of the screen** to determine if I should rotate the `Bitmap`. I could first create a `Bitmap` with `MediaMetadataRetriever` (Because `MediaMetadataRetriever` gives my the correct rotation of the `Bitmap`) and then do it as below:

```
int videoWidth;
int videoHeight;

MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(this, mVideoUri);

Bitmap bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime();

videoWidth = bmp.getWidth();
videoHeight = bmp.getHeight();
```

The I could do the same as above.

---

I will not be accepting my own answer because I haven't tested on multiple device, plus this is a very "hack-ish" way of resolving this issue.

■