# How to check if image in gallery was taken from camera or screenshot?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am uploading an image from my gallery and setting it as a bitmap. In my scenario, whenever I upload a screenshot from gallery,

The bitmap looks clean and fit

But, when I upload a picture which was taken from back/front camera, the bitmap is rotated 90 degrees.

How do I detect if an gallery image was taken by camera or screenshot?

Comment: Images from the camera are .jpg. Screenshots are .png.

Comment: I don't believe the correct solution to your problem is to check if it was taken by a screenshot or a camera. This is a well known bug in Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865183/android-rotates-pictures-by-90-degrees-taken-by-camera

Answer (score 2):

Check if the dimensions of the image fits with the dimensions of the screen. Considering `bitmap` is the image you want to check:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
if(bitmap.getWidth() == size.x && bitmap.getHeight() == size.y){
    // Then is a screenshot
}else{
    // Then is not a screenshot
}
```

Comment: How would I check if it was taken by camera?

Comment: @grant use else statement to take care of the camera images in the above answer by Damia Fuentess

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal There could also be a image downloaded from the internet in the gallery though.

Comment: Then you can try to get the author of the image and check if it's the same as the device

Comment: @grant you can make use of request codes in order to check for the images

Comment: This isn't a real solution to the problem the OP is facing. Plus it's potentially vulnerable to images that come from other apps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great solution, but it's something ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```kotlin
filename.contains("screenshot", ignoreCase = true)
```